# Required Field Validation not hiding

Tags: angularjs

AngularJs form is below.

```
<form ng-submit="doForgotPassword();" novalidate name='forgotPasswordForm'>

    <input type="email" name="EmailAddress" ng-model="credentials.EmailAddress" 
                                                                      ng-required="true"/>
    <span ng-show="forgotPasswordForm.EmailAddress.$invalid" class="help-block">
         Invalid email
    </span>
    <span ng-show="forgotPasswordForm.EmailAddress.$error.email" class="help-block">
         Email is required
    </span>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="forgotPasswordForm.$invalid">
        Forgot Password
    </button>
</form>
```

Problem is: When I start typing an email address and if it is invalid....I could still see required email address validation along with valid email address.

In the screenshot below, we can see the email is entered but still required validation can be seen.

[image]

Can you please suggest the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `required` property of `$error`:

```
<span ng-show="forgotPasswordForm.EmailAddress.$error.required" class="help-block">
     Email is required
</span>
```